# Can I use <asp:textbox> in innerHTML?

Tags: asp.net

I have dropdownlist and I have added javascript to show the contents(e.g. person 1, person 2 etc).
I used below the code but textbox wasn't displayed.

```
innerHtml = innerHtml + <asp:TextBox runat=server ID=txtName3 MaxLength=100 Text=''></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot, as ASP.NET controls are executed on the server, not on the client.

You can add HTML `input` tag instead.

What you probably want to do is to use `UpdatePanel` to refresh part of your page after changing selection in dropdown.